# how to add new <li> to <ul> onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, list

How do I add a list element to an existing ul using a function from an onclick? I need it to add to this type of list ...

```html
<ul id="list">
<li id="element1">One</li>
<li id="element2">Two</li>
<li id="element3">Three</li>
</ul>
```

... another list item with the id "element4" and text "Four" under that. I tried this function but it doesn't work...

```
function function1() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element 4"));
}
```

I don't know JQuery so Javascript only please. Thank you!!

Answer (score 245, accepted):

You have not appended your `li` as a child to your `ul` element

Try this

```
function function1() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Four"));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

If you need to set the id , you can do so by

```
li.setAttribute("id", "element4");
```

Which turns the function into

```
function function1() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Four"));
  li.setAttribute("id", "element4"); // added line
  ul.appendChild(li);
  alert(li.id);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You were almost there:

You just need to append the `li` to `ul` and voila!

So just add

```
ul.appendChild(li);
```

to the end of your function so the end function will be like this:

```
function function1() {
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element 4"));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

First you have to create a `li`(with id and value as you required) then add it to your `ul`.

**Javascript ::**

```
addAnother = function() {
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var children = ul.children.length + 1
    li.setAttribute("id", "element"+children)
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element "+children));
    ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

Check this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/T6XjV/) that add `li` element to `ul`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `innerHTML`:

```js
function function1() {
  ul.innerHTML += `<li> four </li>`;
}
```

Comment: innerHtml is slower and it's XSS - Cross Site Scripting attack prone

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) can be used to set the `textContent` (and the `id`) of the `<li>` element directly, and the return value can be passed to [`Element#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to add the list item to the unordered list.

```js
ul.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {textContent: 'Element 4'}));
```

Full example:

```js
const ul = document.getElementById('list');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  ul.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), 
              {textContent: 'Four', id: 'element4'}));
}, {once: true});
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li id="element1">One</li>
  <li id="element2">Two</li>
  <li id="element3">Three</li>
</ul>
<button>Add item</button>
```