# Add Tab to existing Tab menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

is it possible to add an Tab to an existing tab menu? 
I have a Tab like

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs my-tabs" role="tablist"><li class="dropdown pull-right tabdrop hide"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#tab0" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Write Mail</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Hint</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadTab(2, 'custom', 0)">Custom</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadTab(3, 'Mails', 0)">Mails</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadTab(4, 'customer', 0)">Customer Logs</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Options</a></li>
<li><a href="#tab6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadTab(6, 'smartlog', 0)">Smartlogs</a></li>
```

Is it possible to add a tab with javascript or something else? The Tab is generate by the software herselfe, so I can't add it directly - only with a hook which can insert some code.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can insert/append new `li` tag using JS/jQuery. Though I would recommend moving your click handlers to external script and then pick arguments using data-attributes. That will make it easier for you to add new tabs and handle click events on them also.

Comment: In agreement with @MohitBhardwaj, try to automate this. Generalize the solution from Rohan and generate every tab in code.

Comment: Refer This:<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673959/how-to-add-new-li-to-ul-onclick-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this like,

```
$(function(){
    $('.my-tabs').append(
       '<li><a href="#tab7" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="loadTab(7,\"NewTab\", 0)">New Tab</a></li>'
    );
});
```