# To-Do List with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a simple to-do list. But I want to make a list element have a text-decoration = line-through

When I click the button, the list item will be styled with a line-through and it will remain line-through even when I refresh the page or come back to it in a new request (I think local storage is needed).

I thought I could add a class with javascript but I couldn't find how I can do that with local storage.

Below is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<ul id="a2">
   <li>Make a ramen</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="ka" onclick="laylay()" class="" name="button">A</button>
```

CSS:

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

JS:

```
function laylay() {
var as = document.getElementById("a2");
  as.classList.add("done");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? We need more details such as the code you have failed with currently.

Comment: @basic here what have I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the state of the list across session or requests and you have no backend storage for the list (meaning it is all stored on the client aka via the browser) you will need to use [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Try this.

`localStorage.setItem('a2', 'done');`

Then when the page loads get the item from local storage and set the needed class. 
`localStorage.getItem('a2')`;

You will need to have an [event that fires as soon as the document is ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) that will look into your local storage and see if it finds the record it needs and if it does it updates the CSS style.

```
window.onload(function() {
 var itemStyle = localStorage.getItem('a2');
 var as = document.getElementById("a2");
 as.classList.add(itemStyle);
}
```

This is not a very scalable solution but for your learning and simple example, it will work.

Comment: Have done it but it is not permanent when I refresh all changes are gone

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPKdjw

Comment: That is because you are missing the onload handler. 

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOKpWE

Comment: it makes sense but now the element is always overlined. I don't need to press the button. When page loads it is already overlined. I need to overline it by button and the change will be saved to local storage

Comment: Correct, it is always overlined because that is the state currently stored in localStorage. If you want to toggle the state you need to add more code to your button action to undo the overline if that is the state it is currently in. Per your question, you simply asked how to store the state that it was done (aka overlined). That is what this does. It is not a full solution to the collection a list of to-dos, store the list in local storage on long with their state and have the button handle marking them as done or not done.You delete the state from storage or update code to handle toggle.

Comment: @Kaaleyah I hope this helped. Since you are new, people try to mark answers as accepted if they addressed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the HTML of the element, `document.querySelector("#a2").innerHTML;`, and saving it as a string in localStorage. And when you need to load it again, try checking if it exists in localStorage, then the string will be set as the innerHTML of `#a2`

Comment: I tried something like that but still no result

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPKdjw

Answer (score 0):

You should have array of object stored in localstorage that look like something this:

```
[
{todo:'Do something', complete:false},
{todo:'Do something', complete:false},
]
```

Then when you render todos to page you make conditions based on object what styling your todo should have.
Eg.

```
let todos=localStorage.getItem('todos');
todos.map(item=>{
if(item.complete){
 //code to add this item to page and put .style.textDecoration='line-trough'
}
else{
//code to put item to page
}
})
```

in order to store this kind of object you will need to stringify it when u set it and than when u use it u need to parse it.You can google it out how to do it.
If you are using some framework it will be much easier to render it on page the way you want, but it can be done with js it is just longer code.
Eg.

```
//Way to get items from localStorage
let todos=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos") || "[]");
//Way to set item
localStorage.setItem("todos",JSON.stringify(todos));
```

Comment: Here is link to link where you can see how to add item to ul with javascript:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673959/how-to-add-new-li-to-ul-onclick-with-javascript

Comment: Here is todo that i just made so you can see :
https://codepen.io/Skrbic/pen/YdvqrM