# How to create and fill list item with a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, listitem

I'm trying to create a list of items to be displayed, using data entered into a text field. My trouble is that when I want to add a second list item, the first one just updates. I've tried a few different things and I'm stuck.

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;

  document.getElementById("foodlist").innerHTML =
    (food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.')

};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food"><br>
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount"><br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select><br>

<button onclick="addToList()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button><br>

<li id="foodlist"></li>
```

I want the data from the text fields to create a new list item and add the data to an object every time the button is pressed. all I have gotten so far is the list item just keeps updating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add new <li> to <ul> onclick with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673959/how-to-add-new-li-to-ul-onclick-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create a `ul` element and dynamically create `li` elements, then append them as children of this `ul`. See code below:

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;

  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.';
  document.getElementById("foodlist").appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
<br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>

<br>
<button onclick="addToList()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>
<br>
<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you replace everything using innerHTML. You could just re-use the existing HTML like this (using += instead of +):

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;

  document.getElementById("foodlist").innerHTML +=
    ('<li>' + food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.' + '</li>')

};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
<br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>

<br>
<button onclick="addToList()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>
<br>
<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
```

Comment: This adds texts to the same list item.

Comment: Not anymore. :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you did not create a new list element when you want to append a new item, which is why it keeps replacing the initial value and updating the initial element.

Just need to append new list node to the DOM with the following code when you add a new item and you are all set.

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;
  
  var node = document.createElement("LI");                 
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.');       
  node.appendChild(textnode); 
  document.getElementById("foodlist").appendChild(node)
    

};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
<br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>

<br>
<button onclick="addToList()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>
<br>
<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to append the content.

please change this line `document.getElementById("foodlist").innerHTML =` to `document.getElementById("foodlist").innerHTML +=`

and change `<li id="foodlist"></li>` to `<ul id="foodlist"></ul>`

and `(food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.')` to `('<li>'+food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.</li>')`

```js
function addToList() {
  let food = document.getElementById("food").value;
  let amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  let unit = document.getElementById("unit").value;

  document.getElementById("foodlist").innerHTML +=
    ('<li>'+food + ' ' + amount + ' ' + unit + '.</li>')

};
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" value="food" id="food">
<br>
<input type="text" name="" value="amount" id="amount">
<br>

<select id="unit">
  <option value="oz">ounces</option>
  <option value="lb">pounds</option>
  <option value="servings">servings</option>
</select>

<br>
<button onclick="addToList()" type="button" name="button" id="addButton">add</button>
<br>
<ul id="foodlist"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add `li` elements to a `li` element - the parent element must be one of eith `UL` or `OL`

Each click of the button should call a function to add a new DOM element to the parent node - in this case it will add a new `li` element as required with the content from the other form elements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            form{width:60%;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial}
            label{display:block;width:90%;clear:both;float:none;margin:1rem auto;padding:1rem 0 }
            label > input, label > select{float:right;width:80%;padding:1rem;margin:-1rem;}
            label:before{content:attr(for);text-transform:capitalize}
            button{padding:1rem;width:100%;}
        </style>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{
                let form=document.querySelector('form');
                let food=document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="food"]');
                let amount=document.querySelector('input[type="text"][name="amount"]');
                let list=document.querySelector('ul[id="foodlist"]');
                let bttn=document.querySelector('button[name="button"]');
                let unit=document.querySelector('select[name="unit"]');




                bttn.addEventListener('click', e=>{
                    let li=document.createElement('li');
                        li.innerText = [
                            food.value,
                            amount.value,
                            unit.value
                        ].join(' ');
                    list.appendChild( li );
                    form.reset();
                })
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <label for='food'><input type='text' name='food' placeholder='Food - eg: Venison' /></label>
            <label for='amount'><input type='text' name='amount' placeholder='Amount - eg: 45' /></label>
            <label for='unit'>
                <select name='unit'>
                    <option selected hidden disabled>Please select
                    <optgroup label='Weight'>
                        <option value='oz'>Ounces
                        <option value='lb'>Pounds
                        <option value='gr'>Grams
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label='Volume'>
                        <option value='ml'>Millilitre
                        <option value='l'>Litres
                        <option value='gall'>Gallons
                    </optgroup>
                    <optgroup label='Misc'>
                        <option value='servings'>Servings
                        <option value='items'>Items
                    </optgroup>
                </select>
            </label>
            <button type='button' name='button'>Add</button>
        </form>

        <!-- LI elements are added to a UL, OL or DL -->
        <ul id='foodlist'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```