# when i am updating my list then its not getting updated in the backend the count of list is still the same why?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update a list, but when I add a new element and then count the no. of the element in that list it is still the same as the previous value

here is the code

I am trying to update the section name in the file by clicking on the list its working fine when I don't add any new section, but as I add a new section the eventListener on li stop working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sections</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col col-lg-3">
            <center><h3>Sections</h3></center><hr>
            <ul class="list">

            <li>K19SP</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19PV</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19MA</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19RQ</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19MS</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19LS</li>
            <hr >
            <li>K19DQ</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19MR</li>
            <hr>
            <li>K19OH</li>
            <hr>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-lg-9">
            <center><h3 id='head'></h3></center>
            <div class="sidebar-right col col-lg-3">
             <button class="btns">Add Student</button>
             <button class="btns">Remove Student</button>
             <button class="btns">Upload Assignment</button>
             <button class="btns">View Status</button>
             <button class="btns"> Upload Reading Material</button>
             <button class="btns">Remove Section</button>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-lg-3">

            <input type="text" name="sect" id="sect">
            <button type="button" id="add" onclick="getInput()">ADD</button>

        </div>
       </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js">

</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
this is javascript


 var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    var input = document.getElementById('sect');
    var head = document.querySelector('#head');

function getInput() {
ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li>"+input.value+"</li> <hr>";
}

var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var total = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

for(let i=0 ; i< total ; i++)
{
    li[i].addEventListener('click',() => {  head.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML});
}
```

Comment: You aren't just _adding_ an `li`. You are replacing the entire `innerHTML` of the `ul`. All event listeners will be lost. Use [appendChild()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673959/how-to-add-new-li-to-ul-onclick-with-javascript).

Comment: And another thing, the only valid child of a `ul` is `li`. You should not have `hr` elements as children of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your script with below code. Each time you add a new item , you need add the listener to that `li`.
 `UpdateListener()` will do that for you.

```
<script>
  var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
  var input = document.getElementById('sect');
  var head = document.querySelector('#head');

function getInput() {
    ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li>"+input.value+"</li> <hr>";
    UpdateListener();
}

function UpdateListener(){
    var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    var total = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

 for(let i=0 ; i< total ; i++)
 {
    li[i].addEventListener('click',() => {  

    head.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML

    });
 }
}

  UpdateListener();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var input = document.getElementById('sect');
var head = document.querySelector('#head');

function getInput() {
    ul.innerHTML = ul.innerHTML + "<li>" + input.value + "</li> <hr>";
    var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
    var total = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        li[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            head.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML
        });
    }
}

var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var total = document.querySelectorAll('li').length;

for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        head.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML
    });
}
```

where it adds all the listeners after you modify ul.innerHTML. This is necessary as you're basically copying the `li`s without the event listeners.

However you could do something like this where it doesn't replace the `li`s but instead only adds the newest one.

```
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var input = document.getElementById('sect');
var head = document.querySelector('#head');

function getInput() {
    // named it createdLi to avoid confusion with other variable named li
    var createdLi = document.createElement('li');
    createdLi.innerHTML = input.value;
    var hr = document.createElement('hr');
    ul.appendChild(createdLi);
    ul.appendChild(hr);
    createdLi.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        head.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML
    })
}
};
var li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var total = li.length;
for (let i = 0; i < total; i += 1) {
    li[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        head.innerHTML = li[i].innerHTML
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient route would be to attach one click handler to the `ul` rather than separate event handlers to each individual `li` element. The benefit of that is not only better memory efficiency, but also you'll get the hander working for newly-inserted `li` elements for free. You'll just need a bit more logic in your click handler to identify the specific `li` that was clicked on.

```
ul.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.tagName === 'LI') {
    head.innerHTML = target.innerHTML;
  }
}, false);
```