# innerHTML displaying differently then expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li id=1 class="draggable" draggable="true">
            <div class="input-group" >
               <p draggable="false" style="width:400px; outline: none" >Text</p>
               <button onclick="testFunction(this)">update</button>
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById(1).innerHTML;
         }
         function testFunction(el) {
           var attr = document.createAttribute('contenteditable');
           attr.value = 'true';
           el.parentNode.firstElementChild.setAttributeNode(attr)
           el.parentNode.firstElementChild.focus()
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

When pressing the "update" button and adding new text and lines to the paragraph and pressing the "Try It" button, the new line goes. I expected it to be the same, since I copied the innerHTML.

Comment: `document.getElementById(1)` is not what you want. HTML element `id` values are strings. Use `document.getElementById('1')`, but you should always use element `id` values that start with letters, not numbers.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `.innerHTML` because it's an expensive operation (as it means the text has to be parsed and processed by the browser). It's **much faster** (and simpler, imo) to use `parent.appendChild( other.cloneNode() )` instead, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add new <li> to <ul> onclick with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673959/how-to-add-new-li-to-ul-onclick-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

When making an HTML element and giving it an id, the id must be in quotations, and it also has to contain **atleast 1 character** and **no whitespaces**, so I suggest changing your `li` element's **id** from `id=1` to `id="1a"` (or something with a letter in it), and `document.getElementById("1a").innerHTML` should be changed to that new value (in this instance, "1a")

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting the line to look like a bullet-pointed list, then you need to place the result of the `innerHTML` inside an unordered list.  Right now you're placing it in a paragraph.

Consider changing `<p id="demo"></p>` to:

```
<ul>
  <li id="demo"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so Long story short writing id=1 or id ='1' is not causing any issue.
It is still grabbing HTML and working fine.
The issue is with p tag when you put something inside P tag it starts behaving differently and  (BR) break tag was not showing line breaks. I changed P to Div and it looks fine now.
I changed/removed the CSS class also 
**.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    /* display: flex;**
Now you can see line breaks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li id="1" class="draggable" draggable="true">
            <div  >
               <p id='editable' draggable="false" style="width:400px; outline: none" >Text</p>
               
            </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
<button onclick="testFunction('editable')">update</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <div id="demo"></div>
      <script>
         function myFunction() {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.getElementById(1).innerHTML;
         }
         function testFunction(el1) {
          el= document.getElementById(el1);
           var attr = document.createAttribute('contenteditable');
           attr.value = 'true';
           el.parentNode.firstElementChild.setAttributeNode(attr)
           el.parentNode.firstElementChild.focus()
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```