# Cannot display <LI> items

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I don't know why I can't add LI items to the #historial `<UL>` .

If the for loop  is inside the function, the list is displayed with some elements duplicated. I am almost sure the for loop should be as is now, outside of the function.

Can somebody give me a hand ?

```js
let terminos= [];

    
    function agregar(){

        let termino = document.querySelector('#busqueda').value;
        console.log(termino);

        if( terminos.length >= 5){
            terminos.shift();
            terminos.push(termino);
        }else{
            terminos.push(termino);
        }

            console.log(terminos); 
            document.querySelector('#busqueda').value ='';
           
            
    
    }

        
    let boton= document.querySelector('#enviar');
    boton.addEventListener('click', agregar);

    for( let i =0 ; i< terminos.length; i++){
        
        document.querySelector('#historial').innerHTML += `<li> ${terminos[i]}</li>`;
    }
```

```css
#historial{ 
background-color: tomato;
  width:50vw;
  height:300px;
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<label for="busqueda"> Término</label>
    <input type="text" id="busqueda"> <br>
    <button type="submit" id="enviar"> Enviar</button>
<p> UL#historial</p>
    <ul id="historial">

    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673977/10801086

you should `appendChild` instead  of set the `innerHtml` of your `ul` element

```js
...
 let boton= document.querySelector('#enviar');
    boton.addEventListener('click', function1);

function function1() {
  var ul = document.querySelector('#historial');
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('#busqueda').value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: It's more pedagogic to explain why here, instead of linking to an external guide.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is a very basic scenario and in the simplistic terms, it can be resolved by appending the `li` element to the `ul` element. Please have a look at the snippet.

Hope this helps you. Cheers!!

```js
function addElementToList() {

  var listElement = document.getElementById("historial");
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //this will be your `terminos.length` loop
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("New Element"));
    listElement.appendChild(li);
  }

}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>
    Dynamic list generation:

    <ul id="historial">

    </ul>

    <button onClick="addElementToList()" /> Add New Element
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```