# Dynamic element in getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

I have this code for getElementsByClassName

```
<div id="menu">My List</div>

<div id="menu">
  <div>Coffee</div>
  <div class="lala">Tea</div>
  <div class="lala">Tea</div>
  <div class="lala">Tea</div>
  <div class="lala">Tea</div>
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var num = document.getElementsByClassName('lala').length+1;
    document.getElementsByClassName("lala")[num].innerHTML = "etc";
}
</script>
```

But it just doesn't work.
It only works when I manually put the number in place of the variable

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lala")[2].innerHTML = "etc";
```

I need to insert it after the last class, which is generated dynamically, so I don't know the exact number. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add new <li> to <ul> onclick with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673959/how-to-add-new-li-to-ul-onclick-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about your question.

I can understand the question in 2 ways:

**Way 1:**

You want to insert the last li tag by class `lala` with the content *"etc"*.

You are wrong at the line:

```js
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('lala').length+1;
```

It must be:

```js
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('lala').length-1;
```

And you should set the variable to contain the selector:

```js
var selectors = document.getElementsByClassName ('lala');
var num = selectors.length - 1;
selectors[num].innerHTML = "etc";
```

**Way 2:**

You want to automatically create a new li tag by class `lala` and its content is *"etc"*.

The code to do this is as follows:

```js
function myFunction () {
    var selectors = document.getElementsByClassName('lala');
    var num = selectors.length - 1;
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add('lala');
    newDiv.innerHTML = "etc";
    selectors[0].parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, selectors[num].nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating an `<li>`?

Comment: @charlietfl : I am trying to answer the two ways that I understand question. If way 1 right, OP should skip way 2

Comment: Fine,  but `<li>` is invalid child of `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl : Ah, yes. When I write answer, I see OP's code is UL and LI, and after write complete I see question updated. I will edit my answer. Thank you

Comment: Oh, I didn't see they edit the markup. Unfortunate thing to do

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
function myFunction() {
    var lalaElementsLength = document.getElementsByClassName('lala').length;
    document.getElementsByClassName("lala")[lalaElementsLength - 1].innerHTML = "etc";
}
```

By putting `[lalaElementsLength - 1]` as the index number, you are making sure that you will always get the last element in the list.

You even can shorten the code by omitting the second query for the `lala` elements with the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
    var lalaElements = document.getElementsByClassName('lala');
    lalaElements[lalaElements.length - 1].innerHTML = "etc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then index of array start from 0. Then if you have 3 item, it will be index : 0 1 2

And the document.getElementsByClassName('lala').length return the number of item : 3. Then you should update:

```
var last_index = document.getElementsByClassName('lala').length - 1;
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` is result the instance of `HTMLCollection`, do not an array

Comment: An HTMLCollection object is an array-like list of HTML elements. 
length Returns the number of elements in an HTMLCollection

Comment: You are right, but your answer will confuse js beginners.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lala")[document.getElementsByClassName("lala").length - 2].innerHTML = "etc";
```