# Problem with loop adding all values of an array at a time

Tags: javascript, html, web

Ok so i needed to sort each object using their 'tipo' as parameter. 'urgente' should always be printed first on my screen then 'prioritario'. The solution i came up with was to simply separate em into two arrays then print each array at a time on my screen. THe only problem is that everytime i time to append an array inside my

it appens all the values at a time

ok so heres my html:

```js
let tasks = [
    {
      titulo: "Comprar comida para o gato",
      tipo: "Urgente"
    },
    {
      titulo: "Limpar o quarto",
      tipo: "urgente"
    },  
    {
      titulo: "Consertar Computador",
      tipo: "prioritário"
    },  
    {
      titulo: "Guardar dinheiro do lanche",
      tipo: "Urgente"
    },  
    {
      titulo: "Beber água",
      tipo: "prioritário"
    },    
    {
        titulo: "Alongamento",
        tipo: "prioritário"
      }, 
  ]



  let prioritário = []
  let urgente = []

  for (i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (tasks[i].tipo == "prioritário") {
        prioritário.push(tasks[i].titulo)
    } else {
        urgente.push(tasks[i].titulo)
    }
}


let li = document.createElement('li')
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')

for (i = 0; i < prioritário.length; i++) {
    li.append(prioritário[i])
    ul.appendChild(li)
    
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>ok</li>

    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>
    <li>ok</li>


</ul>
```

Ok so i was expecing three differnet

on my scrren but somehow it is printing everything together like this

[image]

Can you guys please explain to me why this is happening and how to solve it

I don't want to store values as paraphs

Comment: Just a tip: write your code in English, even the comments! It will be easier for everybody else. So, instead of `let prioritário = []`, do `let priorities = []`, etc.

Comment: Regarding your problem, you have to append the `li` as a child of `ul`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20673959/5768908

Answer (score 1):

first, put your `let li = document.createElement("li");` inside your loop so it will create whole new element.

second, you cannot `li.append(prioritário[i])`. appending is for the html element. Thus, make it

```
let li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = prioritário[i];
ul.appendChild(li);
```

```js
let tasks = [
      {
        titulo: "Comprar comida para o gato",
        tipo: "Urgente",
      },
      {
        titulo: "Limpar o quarto",
        tipo: "urgente",
      },
      {
        titulo: "Consertar Computador",
        tipo: "prioritário",
      },
      {
        titulo: "Guardar dinheiro do lanche",
        tipo: "Urgente",
      },
      {
        titulo: "Beber água",
        tipo: "prioritário",
      },
      {
        titulo: "Alongamento",
        tipo: "prioritário",
      },
    ];

    let prioritário = [];
    let urgente = [];

    for (i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      if (tasks[i].tipo == "prioritário") {
        prioritário.push(tasks[i].titulo);
      } else {
        urgente.push(tasks[i].titulo);
      }
    }

    let ul = document.querySelector("ul");

    for (let i = 0; i < prioritário.length; i++) {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = prioritário[i];
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ok</li>

  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
  <li>ok</li>
</ul>
```